# Mac or Windows OS for server communicating with iOS and Android devices

Tags: android, ios, windows, macos, client-server

I am learning to do server-side programming. Currently the server (Mac Mini) should communicate with iOS devices, but I wish to add Android devices to the mix in the future.

I would like to ask in this case, can the server's OS remain as Mac? Or should it preferably be Windows? Or does it not make a difference? Sorry about the n00b question, I'm very new to servers.

Comment: Google suggests Linux for Android. But Mac is OK for both. No need to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the client and server are communicating using a well-defined protocol, the computing platform of either is irrelevant.

One of the simplest and most common methods for a server and client to communicate is via the [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol. All that is required on the server side is a standards compliant web server and for the client side, pretty basic APIs.

You can run the popular [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) web server on a Mac (or Windows, Linux, etc.) server, and use classes like [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on your native iOS apps to communicate with the server.

You have the [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) class on Android.

On the server side, outside of simply serving files, you can easily develop a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)- like API using common languages such as PHP, Ruby, Python, and Perl, that integrate easily with Apache.